# Continue after running help() in Python interactive session

Tags: python, pagination, tty, pydoc

I run the following code in Python Interactive Session and try to get help on the method 'load' from json but i don't know to continue my instructions after (END),

Here is my code:

```
import json
help(json.load)
```

And here is what I got:

```
...
 result of any object literal decode (a ``dict``). The return value of
    ``object_hook`` will be used instead of the ``dict``. This feature
    can be used to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).

    ``object_pairs_hook`` is an optional function that will be called with the
    result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs.  The
    return value of ``object_pairs_hook`` will be used instead of the ``dict``.
    This feature can be used to implement custom decoders.  If ``object_hook``
    is also defined, the ``object_pairs_hook`` takes priority.

    To use a custom ``JSONDecoder`` subclass, specify it with the ``cls``
    kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
(END)
```

Can you help how to continue after (END)? 
(Because I can't type my next instruction.)

Comment: Type the `q` command?

Comment: It will help you in the long run to realize when you are in a "pager" application, and to understand the keybindings of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `q` for **q**uit.

I couldn't find this [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html), but [here it is in the source code of pydoc's pager](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d3f2dc9f8376415a31a6de260ccbe6a86f2816d/Lib/pydoc.py#L1557-L1559).

*Note:* The (END) text hints that `pydoc` may be delegating to another program, [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), for pagination on your platform. However, the same shortcut key should work.

Comment: Actually on my system, it's simply running `less`.

Comment: Maybe you have set the PAGER env var to `less`.

Comment: `PAGER` is not set.

Comment: There is some horrible code in `pydoc.getpager()` which conditionally checks if `less` is executable.

Comment: Do a `man man` which should tell you the default for `PAGER`.  On my system it is `/usr/bin/less -is` but it will vary between installations.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Python will try to use `$PAGER`, but there are multiple fallbacks—it wouldn’t be very useful on Windows otherwise.

Comment: @cdarke That applies only to `man`. On my Debian box, `which pager` is `/usr/bin/pager -> /etc/alternatives/pager -> /bin/less`

Comment: Anyway, I was just trying to point out that the code that `wim` linked to only applies if `pydoc` gives up and runs its own pager. The `(END)` makes me think that the OP is running `less` so he/she should inspect `less`'s keybindings, and not the source of `pydoc`.

Comment: It's a good point, but the pager could be literally anything so we can't enumerate all possible cases here. And the key binding is the same for `less` anyway.